# URLClassLoader trying to get a class from external jar always returning null

Tags: java, spring, jar, classloader, urlclassloader

I am trying to load a class from a jar that is sitting in a directory.
The structure of the class I am trying to grab is as follow:

```
myapp.jar
|__META-INF
|__com
   |__myapp
      |__config
         |__PlumberConfig.class
```

This is how I tried to grab the class:

```
        File file = new File("C:/_workspace/_jar/myapp.jar");
        URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
        URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        LOG.info("URLClassLoader: {}", ucl.getName()); // here always null
        Class c = ucl.loadClass("com.myapp.config.PlumberConfig");
```

The result of `new URLClassLoader()` is always null hence I cannot go further from this point.

I double-checked everything (the path, name of the jar, and location of the class itself) but seems I am still missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working but the method getName() is not defined on URLClassLoader. Try ucl.getURLs() instead. Than it should work as expected.

Comment: The `getName()` method exists since Java 9. The problem is not that the method is not defined but that it returns `null`, which is not surprising as the OP didn’t specify a name.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I looked in Javadoc of Java 8.